# Problem to run the application; showing some error message. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Flutter Fix

```
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ The plugin google_maps_flutter_android requires a higher Android SDK version.                                                                        │
│ Fix this issue by adding the following to the file D:\Development\ULTIMAT POS\App POS Backup\UltimatePOS_Flutter_1.7.1\pos\android\app\build.gradle: │
│ android {                                                                                                                                            │
│   defaultConfig {                                                                                                                                    │
│     minSdkVersion 20                                                                                                                                 │
│   }                                                                                                                                                  │
│ }                                                                                                                                                    │
│                                                                                                                                                        │
│                                                                                                                                                      │
│ Note that your app won't be available to users running Android SDKs below 20.                                                                        │
│ Alternatively, try to find a version of this plugin that supports these lower versions of the Android SDK.       
│
│ For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace minSdkVersion 20 in file build.gradle at folder Android/app/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

in your project folder, look for that file:

```
android\app\build.gradle
```

open it in your editor, and search for this:

```
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
```

replace it with this:

```
 minSdkVersion 20
```